# Responsive gradient background in CSS?

Tags: css, gradient

Is there a way to make responsive CSS radial gradient background? I've tried Microsoft's gradient generator but it doesn't work the way I thought it would, it shows a lot of banding and I would like the gradient to be smooth, it's a basic light gray - white radial gradient.

Comment: an example page? a jsFiddle maybe?

Comment: It's a basic site - http://jsfiddle.net/QjUnJ/

Comment: I can't see anything in your fiddle... have you tried canvas? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_createradialgradient.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background Seams on Mobile Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598781/background-seams-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#grad {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, gray, white);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id = 'grad'></div>
 </body>
```