# Background Seams on Mobile Devices

Tags: css, background, background-image, gradient

Not sure what’s happening, but I seem to have an issue with my background seemingly repeating vertically when view from a mobile device OR if you shrink the browser to activate the responsive nature of the site.

[My Portfolio Website](http://chromahue.com/)

Can anyone give me a hint as to what’s going on here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all because height: 100%; In this case alway when you have vertical scroll this will look like this. So I prefer background attachment, and it should work:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```